# Como verificar campo en MYSQL antes de hacer UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una consulta...

Estoy haciendo un sistema de órdenes de servicio y al cliente se le entrega un PIN secreto

Cuando llega el técnico debe solicitar el pin para cambiar el estado de la orden de PENDIENTE a EN PROCESO

El PIN está en MYSQL 
como puedo hacer para verificar el PIN y si es correcto el técnico pueda cambiar el estado de la orden ?

Estoy con PHP Y MYSQL

el pin está en la columna PIN y el estado de la orden está en la columna ESTADO

Es decir que si el pin es correcto, que haga UPDATE en el campo estado y lo cambie de PENDIENTE a EN PROCESO.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Bienvenido. Tu pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio. Se requiere un intento inicial de tu parte y que plantees la pregunta cuando encuentres alguna dificultad concreta. Entiendo que no sabes por dónde empezar. Pues bien puedo darte alguna pauta: Haces una `SELECT col1, col2 FROM tabla WHERE pin=numPinDado`... Si esa consulta encuentra datos entonces haces el `UPDATE`. Ahí tienes un posible punto de partida. Te toca a ti trabajar ahora. Y cuando tengas dudas concretas puedes preguntar, se te ayudará con mucho gusto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu amable información, me pondré a trabajar en ello y editare mi pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo he logrado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bueno podrías hacer un procedimiento almacenado

enviaras como parametro el PIN del tecnico

y podrias utilizar algo como

```html
IF();
```

para evaluar el PIN enviado con el PIN de la base  te puedes documentar mas sobre este tema aqui
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)